# Does google drive API V3 have a burst limit for requests?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am currently working on a webapp that uploads files to google drive. Depending on the type/category of file, the web app will check for and create an appropriate directory tree to put the file in. Every now and then I am getting this error:

> User Rate Limit Exceeded [403]
>   Errors [
>           Message[User Rate Limit Exceeded] Location[ - ] Reason[userRateLimitExceeded] Domain[usageLimits]
>   ]

I have checked the daily and per minute quotas under the project in the API manager and it looks like we're going no-where near the quota, but still occasionally having this issue.

As I need to make sure files end up in the right directory structure, I am walking the tree which means I am making a bunch of calls to the API as quickly as the API returns an answer.

Does the drive API have any burst limits or as long as long as you stay under the quotas it should work?

Comment: what is the per-user quota for your project on dev console?

Comment: 1000 queries per 100 seconds per user @DalmTo